# Pygame Escape key event is responding to Space key

Tags: python, pygame

I am using "event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE" to pause the game. It pauses if I press esc key. But it is also pausing if I press Space key. And I don't want Space key to pause it. What should I do?

My codes:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_p or pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            if is_paused:
                is_paused = False
            elif not is_paused:
                is_paused = True
                playerY_change = 0
```

Comment: Please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your code

Answer (score 2):

You may have an error on your `if` statement. You need to evaluate it like this:

```python
if event.key == pygame.K_p or event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
```